# Override BasicDataSource in scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-commons-dbcp

I am trying to override the dbcp BasicDataSource class in scala but I am confused by the compiler output. If I try to do the following:

```
class MyBasicDataSource extends BasicDataSource {

}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
class MyBasicDataSource needs to be abstract, since: it has 3 unimplemented members. /** As seen from class MyBasicDataSource, the missing signatures are 
 as follows. * For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations. */ // Members declared in javax.sql.CommonDataSource def getParentLogger(): 
 java.util.logging.Logger = ??? // Members declared in java.sql.Wrapper def isWrapperFor(x$1: Class[_]): Boolean = ??? def unwrap[T](x$1: Class[T]): T = ???
```

But I can instantiate a new BasicDataSource:

```
val ds = new BasicDataSource
```

so it is not an abstract class. I can also override it in java without any such compiler errors. Can someone explain to me why I get these compiler errors?

Thanks
Des

Comment: May it be possible that the scala compiler is running on a jdk7 and the java compiler is running on jdk6 ?

Comment: They are both configured to run on jdk7. Why might this be an issue?

Comment: Are you using commons-dbcp 2.0 ?

Comment: I currently have it configured to use the version from tomcat with the following sbt entry: "org.apache.tomcat" % "dbcp" % "6.0.37". After looking into it I believe this is version 1.x. I am guessing I should be using version 2.0 then?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was using dbcp 1.4 and Java 7 which are not compatible. Upgraded to dbcp 2.0 and that fixed it